# Multiline table cells, display each line as a separate cell

Tags: html, css

i have a structure like this (3 subrows in each cell, but the height of the subrows is different):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>first<br/>row</p>
            <p>second<br/>row</p>
            <p>third<br/>row</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>first row</p>
            <p>second row</p>
            <p>third row</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible format (via css) all subrows to look same as:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>first<br/>row</td>
    <td>first row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>second<br/>row</td>
    <td>second row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>third<br/>row</td>
    <td>third row</td>
</tr></table>
```

**UPD**
I use Tapestry 'grid' component to show some information.
Each row in the grid is an information about one object. Each column is one property. It generate html code like this: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ecy40xo/)
.
I need to show 'id' right opposite correct 'name', not in the center

Comment: Yes, just target the `p` elements.

Comment: "plane data"...Sorry, don't understand.

Comment: If you could tell a bit more your example, that would help to understand why you are asking and what to archive. You are giving two examples while the second seems to be your answer. Help us to understand you.

Comment: @ProtoBassi as I understood, OP can achieve what he wants by altering the html (using table, as shown in second code) but he want to do the same using css only.

Comment: You may want to add an image to clarify your point... Like I have this ... and wants to look like this

Comment: I added some info to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `display: table-cell` to the `p` elements.

```
td > p{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr1o00zc/)**